# AngularFire2 Firestore Dynamic Query: where startTime == currentDateRange

Tags: typescript, timestamp, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

AngularFire2 and Firestore

Goal: Query data from Firestore where startTime == currentDateRange

Question: Troubled with the Dynamic Query in Firestore. I read through the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) and looked at the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularfire-db-api-fbad9p?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) supplied. I have weekly lessons stored in my firestore i.e. (Lesson 1, Lesson 2, Lesson 3, etc). They each have a starTime(timestamp) (December 18, 2017, December 25, 2017, January 1, 2018).

My goal is to have my web page display only the current lesson material for the given week for my students. The weekly lesson would be displayed Monday at 00:00 (midnight Sunday) through Sunday 23:59, Seven Day Date Range).

Then when the new week started again on Monday, I would have the new lesson displayed, in the example here, Lesson 2 - December 25, 2017. Stumped with how to identify the current date, then add the date range, or current day plus six more days.

Moving over from MySql to Firestore. So still very foreign to me. Supplied below is the work I've done so far (with very little success). Image of the Firestore Data Structure, the TypeScript File and the HTML.

First time post on StackOverflow, hopefully I have followed the correct guidelines to submit this question. Thanks a ton for any help you can provide.

Firestore Data

[Firestore Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7x0y.png)

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchmap'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';

export interface Week {
  lesson: string;
  startTime: Date;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css'],
})

export class CalendarComponent {
  weeks: Observable<any[]>;
  dateFilter: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;
  currentDate: new Date();
  endDate: string;// need to figure out how to add seven days from currentDate

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

    this.dateFilter = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.weeks = Observable.combineLatest(
      this.dateFilter).switchMap(([startTime]) => afs.collection<Week>('weeks', ref => {
      let query : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      if (startTime) { query = query.where('startTime', '=>', currentDate) };
      if (startTime) { query = query.where('startTime', '<', endDate) };
      return query;
    }).valueChanges());
}
```

HTML

```
          <ul *ngFor="let week of weeks | async">
        <li >
          {{ week.lesson }}
        </li>
        <li>
          {{ week.startTime }}
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```
endDate = startDate + 7*86400  // 7 days * 86400 ms in a day
```

The problem with just adding dates is it doesn't account for leap days etc.

The best way to manipulate dates in Javascript is with the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library.
Below is an example of how to validate your dates (if you need to) and then add 1 week to get the end date.

```
 if (!moment(this.activity.dates.startDate).isValid())
      this.activity.dates.startDate = moment().toISOString();
    if (!moment(this.activity.dates.endDate).isValid())
      this.activity.dates.endDate = moment().add(1, 'week').toISOString();
```